# How does nested lambda works in racket?

Tags: lambda, nested, racket

I understand how `lambda` works, but when there is lots of nested lambdas, I'm getting confused. Can someone explain how nested lambdas work, and also can someone explain how the given code should be evaluated?

`((lambda (x) (x 5)) ((lambda (y) y) (lambda (z) (+ z z))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(lambda parameter-list body)
```

is a function, that is a program, that, when called with a list of arguments, substitutes the parameters with the arguments and evaluates the body, returning its value.

So,

```
(lambda (z) (+ z z))
```

is a function that, given a certain numerical value, (let's call it `z`), adds that value to itself and returns the result. So for instance, if you call it with the number `5`, it will return `10`.
Let's call this function *doubler*.

On the other hand, the function:

```
(lambda (y) y)
```

is a very trivial function, that returns *any* value passed as parameter. Let's call it *identity*.

Finally, let's consider

```
(lambda (x) (x 5))
```

Noting that in Lisp languages `(function argument-list)` denote calling a function, passing to it a certain list of values, we can see that `(x 5)` means: call function `x` passing to it the value `5`. So the function `(lambda (x) (x 5))` is a function that should be called with a function, and that returns the value returned by calling such function with the value `5`. Let's call this function *call-the-argument-with-5*.

Now we can compose the pieces of the puzzle by rewriting the original expression in this way:

```
(call-the-argument-with-5 (identity doubler))
```

How this expression is evaluated? Working from inside to outside we see that `(identity doubler)` returns `doubler`. So we have now:

```
(call-the-argument-with-5 doubler)
```

That calls `doubler` passing 5 to it. And so the result is 10.

Comment: `call-the-argument-with-5` *could be* a better name. :) parameter is a symbol, argument is a value.

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are called anonymous functions because they don't have a name. But since names are important for human-readability, I think a good way to understand nested lambdas is by naming them.

Functions are just values, and the "evaluation" of programs goes forward by "reducing" i.e. the arguments get substituted into the body (etc. etc. depends on the implementation of the language though)

In `#lang racket`:

```
(define apply-arg-to-5    (lambda (x) (x 5)))
(define identity-function (lambda (y) y))
(define double-function   (lambda (z) (+ z z)))
```

```
((lambda (x) (x 5)) ((lambda (y) y) (lambda (z) (+ z z))))
=
(apply-arg-to-5 (identity-function double-function)) ; 1
=
(apply-arg-to-5 double-function)                     ; 2
=
10
```

1. The identity function applied to any thing is the thing itself
2. applying a function that doubles things to 5 gives you the 5 doubled, i.e. 10.

Answer (score -1):

`lambda(y)` isn't doing anything.

```
(  ;;  open

    ( lambda(x) (x 5) )  ;;  5
    ( lambda(z) (+ z z) )  ;;  self added with self

)  ;;  close
```

returns 10